# Python Multiproccess doesn't run at the same time and separately

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to test how multiprocessing call function at the same time, theoretically, if I have follow code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import numpy as np


def worker(word_id):
    print('hello, my word id is {}'.format(word_id))
    a = np.random.randint(0, 10)
    print(a, 'id {}'.format(word_id))
    if 6 < a < 10:
        time.sleep(4)
        print('hello again, id {}'.format(word_id))
    elif 3 < a < 6:
        time.sleep(3)
        print('hello once more, id {}'.format(word_id))
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('hi, id {}'.format(word_id))


def main():
    process = [mp.Process(target=worker, args=[i]) for i in range(5)]
    for p in process:
        p.start()
    for p in process:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I run, 5 process will seperately call the worker function and to prove that, the random value generate in worker would be random.

However I just got the same value, like this:

```
hello, my word id is 0
2 id 0
hello, my word id is 1
2 id 1
hello, my word id is 2
2 id 2
hello, my word id is 3
2 id 3
hello, my word id is 4
2 id 4
hi, id 3
hi, id 0
hi, id 1
hi, id 2
hi, id 4
```

obviously, the random value I set all the same, I can't tell if it run at the same time or not? Can anybody analysis it and give me an right usage of multiporoccess in python. (maybe it was my code wrong), my perpose is run a function with args at the same time, and I want to know which process finish.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `multiprocessing`, each process inherits the state of the parent. This includes the state of the random number generator. An easy solution is to call `random.seed()` in each worker, once at the beginning. This can fail if your system uses the system time for seeding, but will work well on e.g. Linux where it will get the seed from the operating system.

Comment: thnks for your reply Dietrich, it seems random.random() can generate actually random values separately. don't  know why numpy doesn't.

Comment: It seems that `multiprocessing` calls `random.seed()` itself.  You'll need to do the equivalent for Numpy (although it seems like Numpy is a bit extraneous here).